# Intune- Zero Touch devices

Tags: intune

Is there is a possibility to install an application from unknown source, on a zero touch enrolled android device?

When trying to install  application on a zero touch application, its blocked and states that contact Your IT administrator.

Comment: This sounds very sinister.

Comment: Is there a possibility, Because I am not aware of that.

Comment: I don't think you can do this but have you tried creating an Android device configuration profile that can allow you to install from an unknown source? I am not too sure if it will override policies set under zero touch enrollment but you can give it a try. The safer option would be to publish your app using Intune.